# i have likert data (1 to 5). 50 responses from 150 target population, not a random sample

Tags: statistical-significance, survey, finite-population

Is there a statistical significance test i should use to get a p value that relates to the chances of my data being a true reflection of the population?

Comment: If you only know your sample, there is no way to test this, because obviously you need to know the population in order to know whether they are properly "reflected". One thing you could look at is whether some characteristics of the sample such as age distribution or sex are similar to the overall population, if you know these things of sample and population. This will not guarantee that the sample reflects the population regarding what you are investigating though.

Comment: In what way are your 50 respondents not random as a sample? Is it just that they responded whereas the rest were also asked but didn't respond? Unfortunately it is hardly ever the case that responses of respondents are representative for those who don't respond, as this is an essential difference regarding the question(s). The first thing to think about here is possible reasons for non-response.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time with this Lewian. The target population has 150 people in it. The sample I got from that population (non-randomly) is 50. When I publish that 60% of respondents "strongly disagree" with using animals for scientific research – is there a test that I can use to determine the probability of this finding being true –, in other words what are the chances of me getting the same finding had i got responses from all 150 in my population?

Comment: The sample is nonrandom because it comprises of those people who actually bothered to fill the survey in. All 150 people in the population were asked, only 50 filled it in

Comment: Yes, I guess what I have here is a subsection of the population – those people who can be bothered to fill it in are probably a different grouping from those who did not.

Comment: Aha - i See therefore that there is no point in doing a statistical test in this scenario, the responses I have are just the responses I have – they cannot be used as a true reflection of the target population?

Comment: And I take your point about some kind of comparison of characteristics between my sample and some known characteristics from the target population – that makes sense